# How to fetch data of one table column into another table row

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, fetch

I have 7 tables one is  faculty_subjects rest are Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday and Saturday my tables structure is like this

i have attached image url 
http://s27.postimg.org/434y3255f/School_Management_System.jpg
i tried to make whole design here but everything mashedup

live static page http://www.school.eptins.com/
when someone select class and section relevent to that subjects and faculty display in fields.

Comment: Simplify your code, looking like a GHOST....

Comment: so what is your question? what have you tried?

Comment: Why do you use a table for each weekday? Why not have one table "facultiy_periods" with a "weekday" column? Otherwise you need to join on 7 tables to get a full report.

Comment: thanks all of you for your reply. M_Lill please can u propose a table structure it would be great help for me i have tried a lot stuck in this from last 5 days finally today i posted here....

Comment: thanks bansi for reply my question is how can i display subjects name with their respective faculty for particular class here is live link u will understand what i wanna do as i am new to php and database please help me :( i have made insert page that is working just fine i have asked too many peoples they all said that i need to change schema i have made tables wrong way so plz help me to get this work

Answer (score 0):

I think time-table for one class is a table in itself. Instead of scattering time-table information of a classroom over 6 different tables, you could keep a table name timetable_IA and that table could have first column for periods (Period I, Period II, Period II, ...) and second column for subjects on Monday, third column for subjects on Tuesday, etc.

That way, when a person chooses class IA, you have to just gather information from one table only.

For the second table (Subject Faculty), you could make an array of subjects appearing in time-table by reading time-table of IA, and then call in names of faculty teaching those subjects and construct the table.

Comment: thanks Rahul Ajani for your valuable reply and what will be query for fetching data , delete, update ? can u write query here ?